# Compile OpenCV3 with Cuda7.5 ffmpeg (latest) issue OpenSUSE 13.2

Tags: opencv, cuda, ffmpeg

I am using an OpenSUSE 13.2-X86-64 and a Geforce 940M GPU. I want to work with it on the Qt5 IDE. 
For this purpose, i have installed my GPU Driver with the Cuda7.5 toolkit rpm from the cudazone. Everything is nearly fine. 
It detects everything I have made and executed a couple of the cuda samples.

As next step, i have installed the current FFmpeg version with nvenc and other libraries like Xvid and many of
 the other usefull stuff which would be to much to list it here. After that i have downloaded the current 
OpenCV-3.0.0 source code and ran cmake-gui where i have added cuda, ffmpeg, Qt5 etc and maked it.

On different points of the make session (make -j4) i get this kind of mistake from my console (The list of the Multiple definition
error is much longer). This is the first one.

```
.
.
.
.
.
.
nvlink error   : Multiple definition of '_ZN2cv5cudev16color_cvt_detail15c_HlsSectorDataE' in '/home/peter/Programme/opencv/build/modules/cudev/test/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_cudev.dir//./opencv_test_cudev_generated_test_arithm_func.cu.o', first defined in '/home/peter/Programme/opencv/build/modules/cudev/test/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_cudev.dir//./opencv_test_cudev_generated_test_lut.cu.o'
nvlink error   : Multiple definition of '_ZN2cv5cudev16color_cvt_detail16c_sRGBGammaTab_bE' in '/home/peter/Programme/opencv/build/modules/cudev/test/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_cudev.dir//./opencv_test_cudev_generated_test_arithm_func.cu.o', first defined in '/home/peter/Programme/opencv/build/modules/cudev/test/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_cudev.dir//./opencv_test_cudev_generated_test_lut.cu.o'
nvlink error   : Multiple definition of '_ZN2cv5cudev16color_cvt_detail14c_sRGBGammaTabE' in '/home/peter/Programme/opencv/build/modules/cudev/test/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_cudev.dir//./opencv_test_cudev_generated_test_arithm_func.cu.o', first defined in '/home/peter/Programme/opencv/build/modules/cudev/test/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_cudev.dir//./opencv_test_cudev_generated_test_lut.cu.o'
nvlink error   : Multiple definition of '_ZN2cv5cudev16color_cvt_detail17c_sRGBInvGammaTabE' in '/home/peter/Programme/opencv/build/modules/cudev/test/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_cudev.dir//./opencv_test_cudev_generated_test_arithm_func.cu.o', first defined in '/home/peter/Programme/opencv/build/modules/cudev/test/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_cudev.dir//./opencv_test_cudev_generated_test_lut.cu.o'
nvlink error   : Multiple definition of '_ZN2cv5cudev16color_cvt_detail12c_LabCbrtTabE' in '/home/peter/Programme/opencv/build/modules/cudev/test/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_cudev.dir//./opencv_test_cudev_generated_test_arithm_func.cu.o', first defined in '/home/peter/Programme/opencv/build/modules/cudev/test/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_cudev.dir//./opencv_test_cudev_generated_test_lut.cu.o'
modules/cudev/test/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_cudev.dir/build.make:5302: recipe for target 'modules/cudev/test/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_cudev.dir/./opencv_test_cudev_intermediate_link.o' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/cudev/test/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_cudev.dir/./opencv_test_cudev_intermediate_link.o] Error 255
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1182: recipe for target 'modules/cudev/test/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_cudev.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/cudev/test/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_cudev.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:137: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

And I have no idea how to fix that.

Thx!

Edit: added cmake configuration

```
~/Programme/opencv/build> cmake /home/peter/Programme/opencv-3.0.0
CMake Error: The source "/home/peter/Programme/opencv-3.0.0/CMakeLists.txt" does not match the source "/home/peter/Programme/opencv/CMakeLists.txt" used to generate cache.  Re-run cmake with a different source directory.
peter@linux-3mgc:~/Programme/opencv/build> cmake /home/peter/Programme/opencv
-- Detected version of GNU GCC: 48 (408)
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib64/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.8", minimum required is "1.2.3") 
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib64/libz.so (found version "1.2.8") 
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-video-0.10'
--   package 'gstreamer-video-0.10' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-app-0.10'
--   package 'gstreamer-app-0.10' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-0.10'
--   package 'gstreamer-riff-0.10' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10'
--   package 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10' not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
-- checking for module 'libavresample'
--   package 'libavresample' not found
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h 
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h - found
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found
-- found IPP (ICV version): 8.2.1 [8.2.1]
-- at: /home/peter/Programme/opencv/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx
-- CUDA detected: 7.5
-- CUDA NVCC target flags: -gencode;arch=compute_50,code=sm_50
-- To enable PlantUML support, set PLANTUML_JAR environment variable or pass -DPLANTUML_JAR=<filepath> option to cmake
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2.7 (found suitable version "2.7.8", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so (found suitable exact version "2.7.8") 
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3.4 (found suitable version "3.4.1", minimum required is "3.4") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so (found suitable exact version "3.4.1") 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
-- Found apache ant 1.8.0: /usr/bin/ant
-- Could NOT find JNI (missing:  JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
-- Could NOT find Matlab (missing:  MATLAB_MEX_SCRIPT      MATLAB_INCLUDE_DIRS MATLAB_ROOT_DIR MATLAB_LIBRARIES MATLAB_LIBRARY_DIRS MATLAB_MEXEXT MATLAB_ARCH MATLAB_BIN) 
-- VTK support is disabled. Incompatible combination: OpenCV + Qt5 and VTK ver.6.1.0 + Qt4
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.0.0-dev =====================================
--   Version control:               3.0.0-528-g3a3f403-dirty
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Host:                        Linux 3.16.7-24-desktop x86_64
--     CMake:                       3.0.2
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/gmake
--     Configuration:               Release
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 4.8.3)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fopenmp -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fopenmp -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fopenmp -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fopenmp -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):      
--     Linker flags (Debug):        
--     Precompiled headers:         YES
--     Extra dependencies:          /usr/lib64/libcuda.so /usr/lib64/libnvcuvid.so Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Test Qt5::Concurrent Qt5::OpenGL /usr/lib64/libwebp.so /usr/lib64/libpng.so /usr/lib64/libz.so /usr/lib64/libtiff.so /usr/lib64/libjasper.so /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so gstbase-0.10 gstreamer-0.10 gobject-2.0 gmodule-2.0 gthread-2.0 xml2 ucil glib-2.0 unicap dc1394 xine v4l1 v4l2 avcodec avformat avutil swscale gphoto2 gphoto2_port exif /usr/lib64/libbz2.so dl m pthread rt /usr/lib64/libGLU.so /usr/lib64/libGL.so /usr/lib64/libSM.so /usr/lib64/libICE.so /usr/lib64/libX11.so /usr/lib64/libXext.so cudart nppc nppi npps cublas cufft
--     3rdparty dependencies:       IlmImf ippicv
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 cudev hal core cudaarithm flann imgproc ml video cudabgsegm cudafilters cudaimgproc cudawarping imgcodecs photo shape videoio cudacodec highgui objdetect ts features2d calib3d cudafeatures2d cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo stitching superres videostab python2
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 java python3 viz
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     QT 5.x:                      YES (ver 5.4.2)
--     QT OpenGL support:           YES (Qt5::OpenGL 5.4.2)
--     OpenGL support:              YES (/usr/lib64/libGLU.so /usr/lib64/libGL.so /usr/lib64/libSM.so /usr/lib64/libICE.so /usr/lib64/libX11.so /usr/lib64/libXext.so)
--     VTK support:                 NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib64/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so (ver )
--     WEBP:                        /usr/lib64/libwebp.so (ver encoder: 0x0202)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib64/libpng.so (ver 1.2.51)
--     TIFF:                        /usr/lib64/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 4.0.4)
--     JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib64/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
--     GDAL:                        NO
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.2.2)
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       codec:                     YES (ver 57.3.100)
--       format:                    YES (ver 57.2.100)
--       util:                      YES (ver 55.2.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 4.0.100)
--       resample:                  NO
--       gentoo-style:              YES
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     OpenNI2:                     NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     UniCap:                      YES (ver 0.9.12)
--     UniCap ucil:                 YES (ver 0.9.10)
--     V4L/V4L2:                    Using libv4l1 (ver 1.2.1) / libv4l2 (ver 1.2.1)
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        YES (ver 1.2.6)
--     gPhoto2:                     YES
-- 
--   Parallel framework:            OpenMP
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     8.2.1 [8.2.1]
--          at:                     /home/peter/Programme/opencv/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx
--     Use IPP Async:               NO
--     Use VA:                      NO
--     Use Intel VA-API/OpenCL:     NO
--     Use Eigen:                   YES (ver 3.2.2)
--     Use Cuda:                    YES (ver 7.5)
--     Use OpenCL:                  YES
-- 
--   NVIDIA CUDA
--     Use CUFFT:                   YES
--     Use CUBLAS:                  YES
--     USE NVCUVID:                 YES
--     NVIDIA GPU arch:             50
--     NVIDIA PTX archs:
--     Use fast math:               YES
-- 
--   OpenCL:
--     Version:                     dynamic
--     Include path:                /home/peter/Programme/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Use AMDFFT:                  NO
--     Use AMDBLAS:                 NO
-- 
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.8)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.8)
--     numpy:                       /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.9.0)
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/site-packages
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3.4 (ver 3.4.1)
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
-- 
--   Java:
--     ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.8.0)
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Matlab:
--     mex:                         NO
-- 
--   Documentation:
--     Doxygen:                     /usr/bin/doxygen (ver 1.8.8)
--     PlantUML:                    NO
-- 
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       YES
--     Performance tests:           YES
--     C/C++ Examples:              NO
-- 
--   Install path:                  /usr/local
-- 
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /home/peter/Programme/opencv/build
--        
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/peter/Programme/opencv/build
```

Comment: That looks like a makefile problem (which of course you have not shown us). Try compiling serially and see if it changes anything

Comment: The error is generated with serial compilation. I wanted to check which mistake was the first one.

Comment: Presumably you have a CMakeLists.txt for this project. That would be relevant. What you posted isn't

Answer (score 1):

So after trying and trying again i have solved the problem on a different way. I stepped back from opencv3 to 2.4.11, i stepped back from the latest ffmpeg (this solved a lot of issues). Another problem was that an installed openv-2.4.9 version always wanted to be used and not my cuda compiled libraries. I am not a guy who wants to read in cmakefiles. OpenCV has a whole bunch of that so more than the cmake would definitly a big land of confusion for me.

Nevertheless i have solved my issues. Not with OpenCV3 but with opencv-2.4.11, Cuda-5.0 and which would be enough for my purposes. To get run this combination i wrote some shell scripts to feed back my self and analyse for issues. This file you should run as superuser and replace the name of the user of course or install the files maybe in your custom system.

-- Please not that you maybe have to restart bumbleed daemon,to use mkinitrd and to reboot another time. The second forced installation was done because of the instruction like here --> https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:NVIDIA_Bumblebee
in the endsection. It is proposed if you want to use cuda development.
After this you have to reboot to get it done.

```
mkdir /home/peter/programs
cd /home/peter/programs
# 3rd part library and qt library packages installed. Not even sure that everyone is needed
zypper --non-interactive in gcc git libwebp-devel vtk vtk-devel eigen3-devel libeigen2-devel python-numpy-devel python python3-numpy python3-numpy-devel ant java-1_7_0-openjdk-devel java-1_7_0-openjdk-src python-Sphinx openexr openexr-devel libpng12-devel openjpeg openjpeg-devel tiff jasper libjasper-devel pbzip2 python3-cairo  python3-cairo-devel ilmbase-devel cmake-gui gtk2-devel libdc1394 libdc1394-devel libv4l-devel libxine-devel gstreamer-0_10-devel gstreamer-devel openmpi openmpi-devel openmpi-libs VirtualGL-devel Mesa-libGLESv3-devel ftgl-devel glew glproto-devel gltt gltt-devel gtkglext-devel libGLw1 libftgl2 libglfw-devel libgltf-devel python-opengl gluegen2 gluegen2-devel libjnidispatch gphoto libgphoto2-devel libunicap2 libunicap-devel libucil-devel libucil2 zypper libbz2-devel doxygen jna zypper libQt5Bluetooth5  libQt5Bootstrap-devel-static libQt5Concurrent-devel libQt5Concurrent5 libQt5Core-devel libQt5Core-private-headers-devel libQt5Designer5 libQt5DesignerComponents5 libQt5Gui-devel libQt5Gui-private-headers-devel libQt5Help5 libQt5Network-devel libQt5Network-private-headers-devel libQt5Network5 libQt5OpenGL-devel libQt5OpenGL-private-headers-devel libQt5OpenGL5 libQt5OpenGLExtensions-devel-static libQt5PlatformHeaders-devel libQt5PlatformSupport-devel-static libQt5PlatformSupport-private-headers-devel libQt5Widgets-devel libqt5-creator libqt5-qtdoc libqt5-qttools libqt5-qttools-devel python-qt5 python-qt5-devel python-qt5-utils freetype freetype-devel freetype2-devel dpic libvpx1 libvpx-devel nasm yasm  libopus-devel autoconf automake libass-devel libfreetype6 libSDL-devel libSDL2-devel libtheora-devel libtool libva1 libva-devel libtool libvdpau-devel libvorbis-devel libxcb-devel libxcb-shm0 libxcb-xfixes0 pkg-config latex2html zlib  zlib-devel

# downloading and preparing libs that should be installed form the scratch 
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/opensuse132/x86_64/cuda-repo-opensuse132-7.5-18.x86_64.rpm

mkdir SDK
cd SDK
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/nvenc/v5.0/nvenc_5.0.1_sdk.zip -O nvenc-sdk.zip
unzip nvenc-sdk.zip
cd nvenc_5.0.1_sdk

cd /home/peter/programs
wget http://download.videolan.org/pub/x264/snapshots/last_x264.tar.bz2
tar xjvf last_x264.tar.bz2

wget -O fdk-aac.zip https://github.com/mstorsjo/fdk-aac/zipball/master
unzip fdk-aac.zip

wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/lame/lame/3.99/lame-3.99.5.tar.gz
tar xzvf lame-3.99.5.tar.gz

wget http://downloads.xvid.org/downloads/xvidcore-1.3.4.tar.gz
tar xzvf xvidcore-1.3.4.tar.gz

wget http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-2.6.1.tar.bz2
tar xjvf ffmpeg-2.6.1.tar.bz2

wget  http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/2.4.11/opencv-2.4.11.zip/download  --output-document=opencv.zip
unzip opencv.zip
cd opencv-2.4.11
mkdir build
cd /home/peter/programs
rpm -i cuda-repo-opensuse132-7.5-18.x86_64.rpm
zypper --gpg-auto-import-keys refresh
zypper addrepo http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/X11:Bumblebee/openSUSE_13.2/X11:Bumblebee.repo
zypper --gpg-auto-import-keys refresh

zypper --non-interactive --gpg-auto-import-keys in bumblebee
usermod -G video,bumblebee peter

systemctl enable bumblebeed
mkinitrd

zypper --gpg-auto-import-keys --non-interactive in cuda 

systemctl enable dkms
zypper --non-interactive in nvidia-bumblebee-32bit

zypper --gpg-auto-import-keys --non-interactive in cuda
zypper --non-interactive in cuda-gdb-src-7-5

zypper --gpg-auto-import-keys --non-interactive in -f nvidia-bumblebee
cd /etc/ld.so.conf.d
echo -e "/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64" > cudald.conf
ldconfig

cd /home/peter
echo -e "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH\nexport PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin:$PATH" >> .bashrc

chmod 777 -R programs
reboot
```

I am not sure whether it is a source of issues but after rebooting you maybe open a new shell and run this file. Again don't forget to customize the shell script. Before starting you should extend your sudo session or run it as superuser again.

Remove any other opencv-libs that maybe comes with the rpms. Then you can start this snippet to install it.

-- Note the optirun commands are needed at the end to have at all steps the correct architecture. The configuration sometimes restarts with make or make install. To keep the configuration let it run with optimus.

```
cd /home/peter/programs/SDK/nvenc_5.0.1_sdk
sudo cp Samples/common/inc/*  /usr/include/


cd /home/peter/programs/x264-snapshot*
./configure --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-pic
make
sudo make install
make distclean

cd /home/peter/programs/mstorsjo-fdk-aac*
autoreconf -fiv
./configure
make
sudo make install
make distclean

cd /home/peter/programs/lame-3.99.5
./configure --enable-nasm
make
sudo make install
make distclean

cd /home/peter/programs/xvidcore/build/generic
./configure
make 
sudo make install 
make distclean

cd /home/peter/programs/ffmpeg-2.6.1
./configure \
  --enable-shared \
  --enable-gpl \
  --enable-libass \
  --enable-libfdk-aac \
  --enable-libfreetype \
  --enable-libmp3lame \
  --enable-libopus \
  --enable-libtheora \
  --enable-libvorbis \
  --enable-libvpx \
  --enable-libx264 \
  --enable-libxvid \
  --enable-nonfree \
  --enable-nvenc
make -j8
sudo make install
make distclean
hash -r
echo "Complete!"

cd /home/peter/programs/opencv-2.4.11/build
optirun cmake -D BUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=TRUE -D CUDA_ARCH_BIN:STRING=5.0 -D CUDA_ARCH_PTX:STRING=5.0 -D CUDA_BUILD_CUBIN:BOOL=TRUE -D CUDA_FAST_MATH:BOOL=TRUE -D CUDA_GENERATION:STRING=Auto -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES:BOOL=TRUE -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES:BOOL=TRUE -D WITH_CUDA:BOOL=ON -D INSTALL_TESTS:BOOL=TRUE -D WITH_CUBLAS:BOOL=TRUE -D WITH_NVCUVID:BOOL=TRUE -D WITH_OPENCLAMDBLAS:BOOL=FALSE -D WITH_OPENCLAMDFFT:BOOL=FALSE -D WITH_OPENGL:BOOL=TRUE -D WITH_UNICAP:BOOL=TRUE -D WITH_XINE:BOOL=TRUE -D WITH_QT:BOOL=TRUE -D CUDA_nvcuvid_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib64/libnvcuvid.so.1 /home/peter/programs/opencv-2.4.11/
optirun make -j8
sudo optirun make install
```

With starting qtcreator with optirun iyou should be able to compile and run opencv_gpu files like every other opencv program.

Thx peter